# Django filtering if an object has the specified value or is either isnull

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

I have a view that returns all the users that are either working in or are students in the school that the request.user owns, in my model's I have two fields `works` and `learns` that are foreignkey fields referencing the school object, when filtering the users to match the school that the request.user owns, I have to filter like something like so:

```
class AllUserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    # queryset = User.objects.exclude(type__isnull=True)
    serializer_class = ListUsersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request.user
        if request.type == User.TYPES.OWNER:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True,
                                           type__isnull=False, works__in=request.owns.all(), learns__in=request.owns.all())
        return queryset
```

there is an issue here as users that are working in the school will have the `learns` fields as null and the students will have the `works` field as null so how can I find if either of the fields matches and if they do make it ignores the other field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a condition with a [**`Q`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to define *disjunctive* conditions:

```
class AllUserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListUsersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if request.type == User.TYPES.OWNER:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(works__in=user.owns.all()) | Q(learns__in=user.owns.all()),
                is_active=True, type__isnull=False
            )
        return qs
```

For more information, see the [*Complex lookups with `Q` objects* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: can you please explain to me or reference a link that can explain hoe this works

Comment: @redietyosef: edited. See the see the [*Complex lookups with `Q` objects* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: saying ``'AllUserList' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.``

Comment: @redietyosef: yes, you should specify the queryset. If `is_active` should always be true, even for users that are not `OWNER`s, you can also move the `.filter(is_active=True)` to the `queryset = ...`, and thus omit this in filtering in the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686894/django-error-trying-to-validate-an-email-verification-otp